# How would you calculate the space complexity of this function?

Tags: javascript, recursion, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I've been asked to calculate space complexity for an 'anagram machine'
function I've created. The function returns all possible string combinations by replacing letters. And has a 'memoization' object to help in calculation performance. So the question is: How would you calculate the space complexity of this function?

```js
const arrangeLetters = (function () {
    let dat = {
        memoization: {}
    };
    const arrange = (word) => {
        if (word.length < 2) {
            dat.memoization[word] = [word];
            return [word]
        }
        let curLetter, restOfWord;
        let newEntry = '';
        let allAnswers = [];
        let index = 0;
        let anagrams = [];
        let i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
            curLetter = word[i];
            restOfWord = word.substr(0, i) + word.substr(i + 1, word.length - 1);
            let shortwordArray = dat.memoization[restOfWord] || arrange(restOfWord);

            for (j = 0; j < shortwordArray.length; j++) {
                newEntry = curLetter + shortwordArray[j];
                anagrams[index++] = newEntry;
                dat.memoization[curLetter + restOfWord] = anagrams;
                allAnswers.push(newEntry);
            }
        }
        return allAnswers;
    };
    return arrange;
})();

console.log(arrangeLetters('abefghi'));
```